# How do I add +1 to epoch time using Bash in Mac OS X?

Tags: bash, macos, bsd, darwin

I'd like to add +1 to the epoch time conversion. Right now it outputs `1615715999` & `1` separately, but I'd like for the output to be `1615716000` which is epoch time + 1.

This is on Mac OSX using BASH, any suggestions? Truly appreciate it!!!

```
epoch_s= date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2021-03-14 01:59:59" +%s
    
declare -i epoch_start=$(( $epoch_s + 1 )) 
    
echo $epoch_start
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the command substitution syntax:

```sh
epoch_s=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2021-03-14 01:59:59" +%s)
#       ^^........................................................^
```

No spaces are allowed around the `=`.

The reason you get the output you see is that the `date` output is not stored to the variable, it is emitted to stdout. Then the `epoch_start` variable is assigned the value 1 (an unset variable has value zero in bash arithmetic) which gets echoed on the next line.